# Working with data returned from w32tm

Tags: powershell, time

I am working on an audit script that will be used to audit new client servers before taking them onboard as customers. Currently I am working on the section that will analyse how Windows Time is configured on the server.

I need to pull some data in PowerShell from this command: `w32tm /dumpreg /subkey:parameters`

However what is returns is basically just a table:

```
Value Name                 Value Type          Value Data
------------------------------------------------------------

ServiceDllUnloadOnStop     REG_DWORD           1
ServiceMain                REG_SZ              SvchostEntry_W32Time
NtpServer                  REG_SZ              time.windows.com,0x9
Type                       REG_SZ              NT5DS
ServiceDll                 REG_EXPAND_SZ       %systemroot%\system32\w32time.dl
```

How can I easily extract the `NtpServer` and `Type` from that table into a variable that I can then use later in my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract it using regex. But since these values clearly are stored in the registry(as you could see from the output), I would just extract them from the registry myself.

```
$ntpserver = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters).NtpServer
$type = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters).Type

$ntpserver
time.windows.com,0x9

$type
NTP
```

Comment: *Sigh*. Thanks, can't believe I didn't think of that.... time to just take a break

Comment: Glad I could help. Easy to miss. Usually helps with a second pair of eyes. :)